BottomSheetScaffold's bottom sheet HalfExpanded state doesn't work as it should
I'm using bottom sheet scaffold to show it half expanded and still be able to interact with another part of the screen
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Screen() {
val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
val screenHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp

var sheetHeight by remember {
    mutableStateOf(0.dp)
}

val sheetState = rememberStandardBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = SheetValue.Hidden,
    confirmValueChange = {
        sheetHeight = when (it) {
            SheetValue.Hidden -> 0.dp
            SheetValue.Expanded -> screenHeight
            SheetValue.PartiallyExpanded -> screenHeight / 2
        }
        true
    },
    skipHiddenState = false,
)

val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(bottomSheetState = sheetState)
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

BottomSheetScaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    sheetPeekHeight = sheetHeight,
    sheetContent = {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            // content
        }
    }
) {
    Button(
        modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp),
        onClick = {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.partialExpand()
            }
        },
    ) {
        Text(text = "Click me")
    }
}

}
With this approach bottom sheet kinda breaks and glitches(doesn't hide and returns to half expanded state), but I don't understand what's wrong with it: video
I also tried to use it completely without setting sheetPeekHeight, but it's partially expanded height is much less than half of screen: video

Video link is not working

@GauravBharadia, thank you, updated links

The BottomSheetScaffold behaves as follows according to my findings:

partialExpand() will expand the BottomSheet to the height specified in sheetPeekHeight
expand() will expand the BottomSheet to the full height of the content or the screen height
hide() will completely hide the BottomSheet if you set skipHiddenState = false

The issue you are observing probably is related to the fact that when you set sheetPeekHeight to a certain value, the Scaffold content padding is applied accordingly. So when you change sheetPeekHeight, the contents of the Scaffold will shift.
You can set the sheetPeekHeight to the half height of the screen using LocalConfiguration.current. Then, you can manually subtract the sheetPeekHeight from the padding that is applied to the content of the Scaffold.
Here is the example code:
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
fun SimpleBottomSheetScaffoldSample() {

    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = rememberStandardBottomSheetState(
            skipHiddenState = false
        )
    )

    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetPeekHeight = configuration.screenHeightDp.dp / 2,
        sheetContent = {
            Column(
                Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                    Text("SHEET CONTENT")

            }
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(
                    top = innerPadding.calculateTopPadding(),
                    start = innerPadding.calculateStartPadding(LocalLayoutDirection.current),
                    end = innerPadding.calculateEndPadding(LocalLayoutDirection.current),
                    bottom = innerPadding.calculateBottomPadding() - configuration.screenHeightDp.dp / 2
                ),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Button(onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.hide()
                }
            }) {
                Text(text = "HIDE")
            }
            Button(onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.partialExpand()
                }
            }) {
                Text(text = "PARTIALLY")
            }
            Button(onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()
                }
            }) {
                Text(text = "EXPAND")
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:

